# getServerSideProps query parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Hello I would like with NextJS and his getServerSideProps function send a API Request but i can't transfer my ID Query Parameter.

My API:
http://localhost:3001/product/${id}

My Code:

```
    const router = useRouter();
    return(
        <div>
            {console.log(products.name)}
        </div>
    );
}


export async function getServerSideProps(context){
    const {id}= context.query.q;
    const request = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/product/${id}`);
    const products = await request.json();
    return{
        props:{
            products
        }
    }
}
```

**Here comes undefined**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

its works

```
import {useRouter} from "next/router";

export default function search({products}){
    const router = useRouter();
    return(
        <div>
            {console.log(products[0].name)}
        </div>
    );
}


export async function getServerSideProps(context){
    const id = context.query.q;
    const request = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/product/${id}`);
    const products = await request.json();
    return{
        props:{
            products
        }
    }
}
```